# Mysql index is not being taken while field is mentioned in join on clause

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
explain select * from users u join wallet w on w.userId=u.uuid where w.userId='8319611142598331610'; //Index is taken
```

[image]

```
explain select * from users u join wallet w on w.userId=u.uuid where w.currencyId=8; //index is not taken
```

[image]

As can be seen above, the index userIdIdx is used in the latter case, but not in the former.

Following are the schema of the two tables -

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uuid` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `uuidIdx` (`uuid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `wallet` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `currencyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `userIdIdx` (`userId`),
  KEY `currencyIdIdx` (`currencyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=279668 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How do I force MySql to consider the `userIdIdx` or `uuidIdx` index?

Comment: Are there other columns in these tables?  Why isn't `uuid` the `PRIMARY KEY` in `users`?

Comment: Is there only one row in `users`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methodes improving this.

**Method 1:**

Adding a multiple column index `wallet(userId, currencyId)` looks to be better for both queries.

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aesNYevEzwopmXrnQJRPoS/0

**Method 2**

Rewrite the query. 
This works with the current table structure.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
  SELECT 
   wallet.userId
  FROM 
   wallet 
  WHERE
   wallet.currencyId = 8
) AS wallet
INNER JOIN 
 users
ON
 wallet.userId = users.uuid
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aesNYevEzwopmXrnQJRPoS/3

p.s i also advice you to also add `Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` to the users table when you use InnoDB as table engine.
This post off mine explains why https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48184/27070

Comment: Could you please explain why the multiple column index works in your method 1? Why the single column indexes do not work?

Comment: @SandeepanNath "Could you please explain why the multiple column index works in your method 1? Why the single column indexes do not work?" check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aesNYevEzwopmXrnQJRPoS/4 and see how the MySQL optimizer handles your second query atfer rewritting and optimizing . Take note the rewrite is `join test.wallet w where ((test.w.currencyId = 8) and (test.w.userId = test.u.uuid))`  And also check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.. Do you understand it now? Eazier then this i can't explain.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are doing the best they can with what you gave them.

```
select  *
    from  users u
    join  wallet w  ON w.userId=u.uuid
    where  w.userId='8319611142598331610';

select  *
    from  users u
    join  wallet w  ON w.userId=u.uuid
    where  w.currencyId=8;
```

If there is only one row in a table (such as `users`), the Optimizer takes a different path.  That seems to be what happened with the first query.

Otherwise, both queries would start with `wallet` since there is filtering going on.  Each of the secondary keys in `wallet` is handy for one of the queries.  Even better would be

```
INDEX(userId, currencyId, id)  -- for first query
INDEX(currencyId, userId, id)  -- for second query
```

The first column is used in the `WHERE`; the other two columns make the index "covering" so that it does not need to bounce between the index and the data.

(Geez, those tables have awfully few columns.)

After filtering in `w`, it moves on to `u` and uses `INDEX(uuid)`.  Since that is the only column in the table, (no name??), it can be "Using index", that is "covering".

And the only reason for reaching into `u` is to verify that there exists a user with the value matching `w.userId`.  Since you probably always have that, why `JOIN` to `users` at all in the query??